# Stuck on Fedora splash screen after OpenBox3/tint2 install

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, openbox

My system was bogged down by Gnome3 DE and so I made an install of OpenBox3 and tint2 on a Fedora 17 system yesterday. Both were working marvelously. After a system reboot this morning, my system is stuck on the Fedora splash screen and will go no further.

I tried entering into command line and modifying my `~/.xinitrc` (which I had to create) through vim and then running `xinit` and `startx`, but both returned errors stating the X server failed to run.

Are there any suggestions? I am somewhat new to the underpinnings of Linux, so this a bit more of a difficult puzzle to wade through.

Comment: sometimes you can see in which step Fedora got stalled during the booting process. I don't exactly remember which key is it (up arrow, up page, alt+D; try them as are the ones that come to my head) but this way you can see where exactly did the system failed and therefore you can get a better idea on where is the problem.